# Find all tables with a specific column name and a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I need to update all AccountID columns in all tables where AccountID = '123' to 'xyz'.
I want to make sure I only find tables, not views.
Here is an example how I am try to finding the tables:

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.types y ON c.user_type_id = y.user_type_id
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sysobjects o ON o.name = t.name
WHERE o.type = 'U'
and c.name = 'AccountID'
and y.name = 'nvarchar'
order by TableName
```

I was going about this by finding all tables in the database that have an AccountID column and then running an update statement against each with a cursor using dynamic sql.
I am having problems and I think my query is bring in some views.
There has to be a more elegant way of doing this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `information_schema.tables` and `information_schema.columns`:

```
select t.table_schema, t.table_name
from information_schema.columns c join
     information_schema.tables t
     on c.table_name = t.table_name and c.table_schema = t.table_schema and
        t.Table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to join `Sys.Objects` and `Sys.types` try this.

```
SELECT t.NAME AS table_name,
       c.NAME AS Column_Name
FROM   sys.tables T
       JOIN sys.columns C
         ON T.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE  t.type = 'u' And C.name = 'AccountID'
```